# Why does my MapServer WMS not zoom correctly in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: postgresql, javascript, openlayers, mapserver

Below code is showing the addition of mapserver file in openlayers 3, it is successfully showing me image in the browser but when i zoom that image it does not zoom. It comes back to originial view.

```
  var perimetro = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    url: 'http://localhost:8081/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?',
    params: {
      LAYERS  : 'landuse10' ,
      CRS     : 'EPSG:3857',
      map : 'C:/ms4w/apps/osm/basemaps/osm-google.map',
      mode : 'map',
      FORMAT : 'png'},
    serverType  : 'mapserver',
    extent: [8046840.710000,3906011.335000,8217827.220000,4076997.845000]
    })
 });
 var map = new ol.Map({
   target: 'map',
   layers: [perimetro],
   projection : new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'EPSG:3857',
    units: 'm' }),
    view: new ol.View({
       center: [8046840.71, 3907521.8],
       zoom: 16 })
 });
```

This is my map file layer code:

```
LAYER
  TYPE POLYGON
  STATUS ON
  PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:3857"
  END
  NAME "landuse10"
  GROUP "default"
  CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
  CONNECTION "host=localhost dbname=osm user=postgres password=postgres123 port=5432"
  DATA "geometry from (select geometry,osm_id,type,name as name from osm_new_landusages_gen1 where type in ('forest','pedestrian','cemetery','industrial','commercial','brownfield','residential','school','college','university','military','park','golf_course','hospital','parking','stadium','sports_center','pitch') order by area desc) as foo using unique osm_id using srid=3857"
  PROCESSING "LABEL_NO_CLIP=ON"
  PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"
  MAXSCALEDENOM 650016
  MINSCALEDENOM 325008
  CLASSITEM "type"
  LABELITEM "name"
```

---

I modified the code in this as per told in previous answer but it is still giving me error of "Unexpected identifier".

```
<html>
<head>
<title>MapServer Simple Viewer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/css/ol.css">
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/build/ol-debug.js"  
        type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/build/ol.js" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:800; height:800" id="map"></div>
<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
    var perimetro = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8081/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?',
        params: {
          LAYERS  : 'landuse10' ,
          //CRS     : 'EPSG:3857',
          map : 'C:/ms4w/apps/osm/basemaps/osm-google.map',
          //mode : 'map',
          FORMAT : 'png'},
        serverType  : 'mapserver',
        //extent: [8046840.710000,3906011.335000,8217827.220000,4076997.845000]
       })
        extent: [8046840.710000,3906011.335000,8217827.220000,4076997.845000]
    });
    var map = new ol.Map({
       target: 'map',
       layers: [perimetro],
       projection : new ol.proj.Projection({
          code: 'EPSG:3857',
          units: 'm'
       }),
       view: new ol.View({
           center: [8046840.71, 3907521.8 ],
           zoom: 16
           })
       });       
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just added variables breaking the normal OpenLayers 3 behaviour and also made a mistake about extent position

Remove

```
mode : 'map',
CRS     : 'EPSG:3857',
```

Move

```
extent: [8046840.710000,3906011.335000,8217827.220000,4076997.845000]
```

from `ol.source.ImageWMS` to `ol.layer.Image` options block

Comment: I moved it from ol.source.ImageWMS to ol.layer.Image but it gives me error of Unexpected identifier. I am posting that new code in another answer please have a look at that one. Is this what were you saying?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that your center point falls on the edge of the extent you choose for your WMS.

Try changing the extent or choose a point which falls within your extent at zoom level 16 (or change zoom level to 5).

You can check with the following code where I have changed the ol.layer.Image to ol.layer.Tile.

```
var perimetro = new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'WMS',
        visible: true,
        extent: [8046840.710000,3906011.335000,8217827.220000,4076997.845000],
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost:8081/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe',
            serverType: 'mapserver',
            params: {
                'MAP': 'C:/ms4w/apps/osm/basemaps/osm-google.map',
                'LAYERS': 'landuse10',
                'TILED': true,
                'SRS':'EPSG:3857'
            }
        })
    });

    var proj : new ol.proj.Projection({
          code: 'EPSG:3857',
          units: 'm'
       });

    var view = new ol.View({
        center: [8046840.71, 3907521.8],
        zoom: 16
        });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [perimetro],
        target: "map",
        projection: proj,
        view: view
    });
```

Hope this should work. If not, then revert with the error in browser Console. All the Best